# Remove Measure Toolbar Button from Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the autodesk forge viewer and want to remove the 'measure' tool from the toolbar. I have tried the following but it will not remove the 'measure' button

```
const onToolbarCreated = (e) => {
        const settingsTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('settingsTools')
        
       // settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-modelStructureTool') 
      //  settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-propertiesTool')            
        settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-settingsTool');
        settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-measureTool');   
     //settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-fullscreenTool')        
    }
```

All of the other removeControl() functions work other than the one for the measure-tool. Any guidance on how I could remove this button from the viewer would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

EDIT: I have tried this without success

```
const onToolbarCreated = (e) => {
        const settingsTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('settingsTools');
      
   const modelTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools');
   modelTools.removeControl('toolbar-measurementSubmenuTool');
       // settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-modelStructureTool') 
      //  settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-propertiesTool')            
        settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-settingsTool');
        //settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-measurementSubmenuTool');   
     //settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-fullscreenTool')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning to use it anymore you can simply unload the extension from your project.

```
viewer.unloadExtension("Autodesk.Measure");
```

Answer (score 1):

Measure tool is in `modelTools` group.

```
const modelTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools')
modelTools.removeControl('toolbar-measurementSubmenuTool')
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it out. I cannot remove the measure button @varunpatil

Comment: The following removes, the explode, measure, and set-box buttons. However i only want to remove the measure tool.                 viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools').setVisible(false);

Comment: It's removing only measure tool, just run these 2 lines in browser console.
`
const modelTools = NOP_VIEWER.toolbar.getControl('modelTools')
modelTools.removeControl('toolbar-measurementSubmenuTool')
`

Comment: That works! Where can I put this in my code to remove the measure-tool @varunpatil

Comment: same place, inside onToolbarCreated. Anyways, if you're not using it, the accepted answer is simpler.